# Context menu opens (long press detected) when swiping View out

Tags: android, contextmenu, swipe, ontouchlistener, long-press

I am using the the OnSwipeTouchListener found here:

https://github.com/seanoshea/krissytosi-android/blob/master/krissytosi/src/com/krissytosi/utils/OnSwipeTouchListener.java

The way that I have implemented, I have two RelativeLayouts that sit on top of each other, and each one has a OnSwipeTouchListener that animates the layouts out and in depending on which way the swipe is. This allows the user to easily switch between two Views that share part of my layout.

Today I registered one for the context menu. I'd like to have a floating menu come up when it is long pressed. This works fine, however when swiping this View away, the floating menu pops even when the swipe is detected and the animation occurs.

I have tried a few things:

I tried using an AnimationListener to unregister the View for the context menu when the animation begins, and then register it when the animation finishes. The context menu still appeared.

I tried using an AnimationListener to set a boolean isSwiping to true as the animation is orrucing, and then set isSwiping to false when the animation finishes. Then in onCreateContextMenu, I only inflate the context menu if isSwiping is false. The context menu still appeared.

This all leads me to believe that the long press is detected before the swipe animation occurs. So, how can I make it so that the user is able to swipe between the two layouts, while not creating the context menu?

Thanks in advance!